# Android error that i can't understand. Can someone help me?

Tags: android, sdk, runtime-error, searchview

I have built a sql database and i have implement the searchview widget to ba able to use in android pre API 11

When i try to do a research, the application close itself and i get this error and other messages:

Error

```
  08-19 15:15:25.560: E/dalvikvm(6838): Could not find class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.addOnLayoutChangeListenerToDropDownAnchorSDK11        
 08-19 15:15:25.560: I/dalvikvm(6838): Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5; interface 814 'Landroid/view/View$OnLayoutChangeListener;'             
 08-19 15:15:25.560: W/dalvikvm(6838): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5;' failed    
 08-19 15:15:25.560: D/dalvikvm(6838): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0002   
 08-19 15:15:25.560: D/dalvikvm(6838): VFY: dead code 0x0004-000a in Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView;.addOnLayoutChangeListenerToDropDownAnchorSDK11 ()V
```

I don't know if is something wrong with my code or else.
There's someone can help me?
Thank you

i think the error is here

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity{
DatabaseTable db = new DatabaseTable(this);
final Context context=this;
ListView list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }


    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Cursor c = db.getWordMatches(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();    
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to import android.support.v7.widget.Searchview, but it says that is never used, and the error doesn't disappear. for this project, i have created the MainActivity.Java, wich contain the SearchWidget, a DatabaseTable.java a definitions.txt wich contains the data, a Search.xml and a SearchActivity.Java (the code below), i have also put the meta tag in the MainActivity and in the SearchActivity, inside the Manifest, don't know if can bel Helpfull to insert here the code of every page...I really don't know what to do anymore !!

Sure, here's the code of my main activity

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.SearchManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
    import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{




    ActionBar actionBar;
    Button a;
    Button b;
    Button c;
    Button d;
    Button e;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Trial");

        initialiseOnClick();
        a.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        c.setOnClickListener(this);
        d.setOnClickListener(this);
        e.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

        //START SEARCHVIEWWIDGET
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)     getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)     MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
       searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); 
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    // END SEARCHVIEWWIDGET

    private void initialiseOnClick() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_a);
        b = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_b);
        c = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_c);
        d = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_d);
        e = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button_e);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.button_a:
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EuropeActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
        break;

        case R.id.button_b:
            Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AmericasActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
        break;

        case R.id.button_c:
            Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AsiaActivity.class);
            startActivity(c);
        break;

        case R.id.button_d:
            Intent d = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OceaniaActivity.class);
            startActivity(d);
        break;

        case R.id.button_e:
            Intent e = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AfricaActivity.class);
            startActivity(e);
        break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using the support library version of the search view. Are you sure you have added the support library to your project, and if so is it the latest version

Comment: Hi, yes, i use the support library, i have downloaded the latest library available, do you think ii can try to remove and reinstall the library?

Comment: Yea won't hurt it looks like your app can't find it. If you remove the jar from the libs folder and then right click on project > Android Tools > Install Support Library

Comment: I think my error is in this code, unfortunatly is my first app with the searchview, i am not very good yet :(

Comment: i have reinstall the library, now the errors are disappear, bt i get some other errors, i think the problem is in the code above. Sorry, this is my first app with searchview, i am not very clear with it yet :(

Comment: i was wrong, the same error still exist

Comment: I can't see that you're importing the support library at the top of class. Didn't notice before. If you use the intellisense (auto complete) and select the support version of the class it will automatically do the import

Comment: Thanks Boardy for your reply... honestly, i didn't understand so much what you are try to explain. Could you explaime me what to do? Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about the search view but whatever class that creates it if you start typing the class name and press Ctrl + Space for the auto complete. Then in the list there would likely be the standard class and the class within the support library. Select the support version and this will automatically do the import. At the top there should be something like import android.support.v4... in order to reference the support library

Comment: I have tried to import android.support.v7.widget.Searchview, but it says that is never used, and the error doesn't disappear. for this project, i have created the MainActivity.Java, wich contain the SearchWidget, a DatabaseTable.java a definitions.txt wich contains the data, a Search.xml and a SearchActivity.Java (the code below), i have also put the meta tag in the MainActivity and in the SearchActivity, inside the Manifest, don't know if can bel Helpfull to insert here the code of every page...I really don't know what to do anymore !!

Comment: Can you add the code for your MainActivity which contains the search widget

Comment: AI have added the mainactivity

Comment: I could be completely wrong as I don't know much about the search widget but have you tried changing ``import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;`` to ``import android.support.v4.widget.SearchView;`` to match the others. I've not heard of a v7, I know eclipse always installs v4 so this maybe why it can't find the class. Maybe http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html will also help

Comment: I tried, it doesn't exist such class

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've run out of possible ideas I'm afraid